# Scroll ActionBar up and hide with scroll in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-recyclerview

I want to achieve the scrolling technique used in Google Play Store app. The app portrays tabs below action bar. Once the content is scrolled up, it pushes the action bar up and finally hides it. At that point the tabs remain sticky at the top.

I tried the following code, but the flickering is there -

```
    mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        private static final int SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP = 1;
        private static final int SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN = 2;

        private int verticalDirection;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
                if (verticalDirection == SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP && getActivity().getActionBar().isShowing()) {
                    getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
                } else if (newState == SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN && !getActivity().getActionBar().isShowing()) {
                    getActivity().getActionBar().show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy > 0) {
                verticalDirection = SCROLL_DIRECTION_UP;
            } else {
                verticalDirection = SCROLL_DIRECTION_DOWN;
            }
        }
    });
```

Also, I'm not using `ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` as I didn't find any justification to use it in my use case.

Can anyone point me to any resource regarding this?

Comment: tried to use the ToolBar?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, I tried using the Toolbar, now the flickering is gone. However the show / hide animation is a lot quicker now, and the toolbar kind of snaps and doesn't go away with a smooth transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can easily achieve this using the official **Android Design library**. 
Check this example:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare